# CRAN submission frequency and debugging

Tags: r, package, cran

How  often should one update a package on CRAN? I noticed `NOTE`s in the CRAN checks that I have since solved. 
However, I just discovered that the("my"(disclosure)) package now fails to install on one of the Linux flavors. How can I best know what is causing the error as the logs simply show:

> - installing to library ‘/home/hornik/tmp/R.check/r-devel-gcc/Work/build/Packages’
>     Error: ERROR: no permission to install to directory ‘/home/hornik/tmp/R.check/r-devel-gcc/Work/build/Packages’
>     Secondly, if I fix this problem, how long should I wait before submitting to CRAN? I was ideally thinking of taking a month or so as I read somewhere. 
>     Thanks in advance.

[CRAN checks](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_manymodelr.html) for reference.

**EDIT::** I discovered that there are some issues with `dplyr` as per its CRAN checks, could this be causing the problem?!

Comment: I try to limit myself to about every 6 months. However, if my package actually fails the CRAN checks, I'd try to rectify as soon as possible unless (i) it fails on R-oldrel because the package requires a newer R version or (ii) it fails on R-devel. In the latter case I give it a few days to see if it sorts itself out. I just looked and my package fails with the same error as yours. I don't depend on dplyr (but on data.table, which also contains compiled code).

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what happens after a few days and will also keep the advice regarding submission frequency in mind.

Comment: And the error disappeared. :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the most used [guidelines for releasing R packages on CRAN](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/release.html) says

> Do not submit updates too frequently. The policy suggests a new
> version once every 1-2 months at most.